# Different configuration for each kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have `Kubernetes Deployment` with 10 pods.

And I have 10 directories path in my database table (path_table) as follow:

```
path,id
c:\dir1, 1
c:\dir2, 2
...
c:\dir10, 10
```

I want to configure each pod to look on different path from DB.
Means - pod1 will monitor `c:\dir1`, pod2 will monitor `c:\dir2`,etc..

How can I make each pod start with different query from db to take it's path, example:

pod1 start with `select path from path_table where id=1`

pod2 start with `select path from path_table where id=2`

...

Comment: I don't think it is possible with `Deployment` as the pods in a `Deployment` are independent replicas of the same application with no state. You might want to look at [`StatefulSets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) where each pod has a state that can be used to work on a specific directory as you require.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia, Can you please post an answer how can I do it using StatefulSets please? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't think it is possible with `Deployment` as the pods in a `Deployment` are independent replicas of the same application with no state.

You might want to look at [`StatefulSets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) where each pod has a [unique name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#ordinal-index) that can be used to work on a specific directory as you require.

You can pass the pod name as the environment variable to the pods which has a unique id in case of `Statefulset`:

```
env:
      - name: MY_POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
```

So, if you have ten replicas of a `Statefulset` with name `myapp` then the pods will have the names as `myapp-0`, `myapp-1` and so on.

You can then internally use these names to work on specific directories based on the env value of `MY_POD_NAME`.